# Bad operand types for binary operator '+' after trying to fill a new array

Tags: java

I'm trying to put all the integer converted elements into a new array, but I keep getting the error saying "Bad operand types for binary operators "+".

```
char[] array = input.toCharArray();
int[] myArray;

for (int i = 0, n = array.length; i < n; i++) {
  char character = array[i];
  int ascii = (int) character;
  **myArray** += ascii;
}
```

I was expecting myArray to get filled with the newly converted integers, but It doesn't work apparently.

Comment: what do you think about this line `**myArray** += ascii;` and where are you initializing `myArray`?

Comment: myArray += ascii line does not make sense, you cannot assign int value to int[].

Comment: You cant add to array like this ,use arraylist instead,like `ArrayList<Integer> a,a.add(ascii)`

Comment: Why are you converting the `char[]` to an `int[]` up front, instead of casting when you actually need the value for an element from that char array as an integer?

Answer (score 1):

First initialise the `myArray`

```
int[] myArray = new int[array.length];
```

Then in the for loop just add `int ascii` to myArray

```
myArray[i]=ascii;
```

And your for loop is also wrong which is invalid, for loop consists of three part (initialisation, condition, increment) i will suggest you to go through some basics on loops concepts

```
for (int i = 0, i < array.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use n = array.length everytime.

```
char[] array = input.toCharArray();
        int[] myArray = new int[array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            char character = array[i];
            int ascii = (int) character;
            myArray[i] = ascii;

        }
```

Comment: myArray is getting filled but the elements are "[I@579bb367" instead of numbers?

Comment: You are trying to print reference of array by doing System.out.print(myArray);
Please try to iterate over length of array and print each element. Or other option is to refer link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array